# How to select top rated photos in the last few days?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is my data context:

```
Photos (ID, Title)
Users (ID, FullName)
Ratings (PhotoID, UserID, Value, Date)
```

Business rules:

- users can rate a photo from 1 to 5
- a given user can rate a given photo only once

I want to select the top rated photos by day in the last let's say 3 days. So which photo got the best rating today, yesterday and the day before yesterday? I would like to make the number of days variable if it possible. I have to display the last N days only they rated excluding empty days.

I would like to get the photos in a single query/result because I want to bind it to a ListView to display them on a web form.

I've started this way:

```
DECLARE @days INT = 3

SELECT TOP (@days) ... FROM Ratings
INNER JOIN Photos ON Photos.ID = Ratings.PhotoID
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day, [Date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(day, [Date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) DESC
```

How can I group my groups by PhotoID, order them by SUM(Value) and select the first one from each group? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I've edited my question there you can see my few lines of code. I think my problem is a common one so I started searching for the solution yesterday. But I had no luck, I could not construct a well formed search query that would bring me to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Date, TotalRating, Photos.*
FROM Photos
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNumber, 
        PhotoID, Date, TotalRating
 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date, ORDER BY TotalRating DESC) AS inRowNumber,
              PhotoID, Date, TotalRating
        FROM (SELECT PhotoID, Date, SUM(Value) AS TotalRating
              FROM Photos
              GROUP BY PhotoID, Date
              HAVING SUM(Value) > 0 ) t)
 WHERE inRowNumber = 1) t ON Photos.Id = t.PhotoID
 WHERE RowNumber <= @days
```

Comment: You need to restrict the inner select to the last 3 days.

Comment: @ypercube btw, is it "eye-per-kyoob" or "why-per-kyoob"? And what is the etymology? (Maybe a note on your profile?)

Comment: @Bohemian: I guess the first one. Etymology is from hypercube (from the days when some machines limited (directory) names to 8 chars :)

Comment: My guess is that the OP wanted to order by the average rating, rather than sum of ratings, for each photograph.  Perhaps some additional weighting for photographs with many ratings, i.e. they all come out on a scale of 1 to 5, but one with a 4.5 average over 100 ratings might beat a 4.5 with 2 ratings.

Comment: First of all thank you for your comment. I've tried your query but it yields only one row. I would like to get the best photos by day in a single result.

Comment: @user92546 In this example I do not need any special weighting, SUM or AVG are enoguh.

Comment: I've edited my question please see the details. I am sorry I was not clear enough.

Comment: @BlueCode Check it out now, hopefully this is what you are looking for